# Bootstrap Modal not displaying without internet access

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal for preview before submitting which works properly with any of my browsers that are connected with the internet. However, my modal is not displaying on the computers which have no access to certain websites. I tried checking the browser's versions. I've also downloaded every bootstrap and jquery script and included in my file but still doesn't work.

Here's what I've included in my code

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
<script src="jquery-3.4..min.js"></script>
```

Here's the exact code I used and for reference

[Display form input in Bootstrap MODAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513633/display-form-input-in-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: Have you looked on `console` for errors ? Any error occurred when you try to open modal in those particular systems?

Comment: Code which you have posted here include many online libraries. Provide code with local includes and share your console log details too.

Answer (score 0):

You have used **cdn** which will require internet access while the page loads to download scripts and css.

In case you want to use it without internet download bootstrap and place it in your directory & use it.